# filesizeformat filter not working?

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to simply render a size in bytes to a string which describes it in human-readable format:

```
$ python -c "import jinja2 ; print jinja2.Template(\"{{ bytes|filesizeformat }}\").render(bytes=1572864)"
0.0 MB
```

Unfortunately, I always get `0.0 MB` as the result. Why am I not getting a real value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filesizeformat` filter was [fixed in version 2.7](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/CHANGES)

The fix, however, is really simple, involves only two lines of code, and you can implement it yourself. See [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/commit/7d268bef0e8f3f12c0acb90f30d67726a3e3f261).