# Google App Engine filesizeformat issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

When using the filesizeformat filter from jinja2 with Google App Engine, the issue stated here: [filesizeformat filter not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366325/filesizeformat-filter-not-working)
is still happening. This is because app engine still uses jinja2 version 2.6. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: You can include your own, newer version of Jinja2 in your project.

Comment: The function might be blocked on the GAE environment. Most File operations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import your own libraries for jinja2 by doing what's explained in ['Can I import my own version of a module that is included with Google App Engine?'](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks#import)